# Alter X axis labels on ROC curve

Tags: r, roc

I have performed a logistic regression and have plotted a ROC curve in R. I would like to alter the x and y axis labels however, am having trouble doing so. I have managed to suppress the previous axes but can't seem to display the new ones that I create. As you can see below, I would like the y axes (left) to run from 0 - 100 in increments of 20. I'm clearly doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
plot(roc.val, xlab = "Specificity (%)", ylab = "Sensitivity (%)", axes = FALSE)
axis(2, at=seq(0,100, by=20))
```

When I run this code I end up with a figure that looks like this;

[image]

Comment: I find that a lot of analysts are using ROC curves without a real reason.  I don't see them as provide insights or actionable intelligence.  Just some unsolicited advice to question the need for such curves.  If you want to measure pure discrimination ability of the logistic model you can use the $c$-index (concordance probability) which happens to equal the area under the ROC curve.  The R `rms` package's `lrm` function gives you this and many more indexes for logistic model performance.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am using the AUC however, I believe that it is important to display the AUC visually also therefore the ROC curve is required.

Comment: Required by whom?  What insight does it provide?  I have seen thousands of these curves and have never taken action because of them.  They also invite the terrible practice of thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this issue. I needed to convert the x and y axis values to percentages by multiplying by 100 before the x and y axis labels would appear. Please see the code I used below if you have a similar issue.

```
axis(2, at = seq(0,1,by=.2), labels = paste(100*seq(0,1, by=.2)), tick = TRUE)
```